# strconv.ParseInt: parsing "18446744073709551615": value out of range

Tags: go, uint64

Is it a normal behavior when parsing uint64 max value with `strconv.ParseInt`?

```
i, err := strconv.ParseInt("18446744073709551615", 10, 64)
fmt.Println(i, err)
```

I got an error: `"strconv.ParseInt: parsing "18446744073709551615": value out of range"`, when maximum allowed value for uint64 is: 18446744073709551615

Can you explain such behavior?

https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go?s=1026:1044#L26

Comment: probably you need `ParseUint`

Comment: @PenelopeStevens answers go down there v v v :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call ParseUint to parse an unsigned integer.

The ParseInt function parses signed integers.  The maximum signed integer is 9223372036854775807.

Answer (score 5):

Based the comments ,I reproduced your code as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    i, err := strconv.ParseUint("18446744073709551615", 10, 64)
    fmt.Println(i, err)

}
```

Output:

```
18446744073709551615 <nil>
```